# How can I simplify or write the following definition in standard mathematical format?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions, symmetric-functions

$\gamma(r,n,d)$ is an integer defined as follows:
for all $d|n$, $0<=r<=n-1$ 
call $u1$ the list $\mu(s) (d/s)$ over all divisors $s|d$,
for n=6, and d=1,2,3,6 respectively we get {1}, {2,-1}, {3,-1}, {6,-3,-2,1} (summing to $\phi(d)$).
call $u2$ the intersection of the divisors of n with the divisors of $r$
(if fact, for n=6, we want this intersection to be with the divisors of 1 .. 6 but will be counting $r=$ 0 .. 5 using $1+{(k-1)\bmod 6}$).
for n=6,  r=0..5 the six tuples of $u2$ are 
{1,2,3,6}, {1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,2}, {1}
then $\gamma(r,n,d)$ equals the sum of the (signed) d-th element in $u1$ whose absolute value occurs in the (r+1)-th part of $u2$.
I could not find a more concise description or notation, and would be very surprised if $\gamma(r,n,d)$
didn't show up in other combinatorial contexts.

Example 1:
choose $n=6$ and $r=3$
$u1=$ {1}, {2,-1}, {3,-1}, {6,-3,-2,1} for $d$ ={1,2,3,6} respectively.
$u2=$ {1,3} from $\{1,3\} \cap \{1,2,3,6\}$
so $\gamma(3,6,1) = 1$; $\gamma(3,6,2) = -1$; $\gamma(3,6,3) = 3-1 =2$; $\gamma(3,6,6) = -3+1= -2$

Motivation :

I encountered it in the following context:
the principal specialisation of the Schur function $s_\lambda(1,q,q^2,..,q^{n-1}) , \lambda \vdash n$ is given by 
$q^{b(\lambda)} \prod_{u \in \lambda},[n+c(u)]/[h(u)]$ 
with $b(\lambda) = \sum{_i} (i-1) \lambda_i $ and $[x] = (1-q^x)$ and with $h(u)$ the hooklength of cell u, and similarly $c(u)$ the content of cell u (see R. P. Stanley (Enum. Comb. Vol. 2 (1999) pg 375 Theorem 7.21.2).
The resulting polynomial in q has degree at most $n (n-1)$. If we choose q so that $q^k = q^{k\bmod n}$ like in $q=e^{i \pi k/n}$ then the $n(n-1)$ terms are collapsed into $n$.
These can be calculated directly. Choose any value $r$ in the range 0 to n-1. The coefficient of $q^r$ seems to be given by:
$c_r(\lambda)= (1/n) \sum _{d|n} \beta_d(\lambda) \delta_d(\lambda) \gamma(r,n,d) \prod_{j=1}^d t
(\lambda_j,n/d)$
where $\beta_d(\lambda)$ is $1$ iff the d-core of $\lambda$ is empty, else 0 ;
$\delta_d(\lambda)$ is the sign of the $d$-quotients of $\lambda$
(see [http://web.math.ku.dk/~olsson/manus/comb_rep_all.pdf](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7Eolsson/manus/comb_rep_all.pdf)  *(pg 22, example following remark 3.11).*

$t(\lambda_j,n/d)$ is the count of SSYT of j-th d-quotient of $\lambda$ with max element $n/d$
(Stanley's hook content formula).


Example 2:
n=6; $\lambda = \{4,1,1\}$
all d-cores of $\lambda$ are empty, so all $\beta_d$ are $1$.
The signs of the $d$-quotients $\delta_n(\lambda)$ are {1,-1,1,1} for $d$={1,2,3,6} respectively.
The d-quotients are the following $\lambda_j$ :
d=1; {4,1,1}
d=2; {} , {2,1}
d=3; {2}, {}, {}
d=6; {}, {}, {}, {1}, {}, {}
and so the product over $t(\lambda_j,6/d)$ equals
d=1; $t(\{4,1,1\},6) = 840$
d=2; $t(\{2,1\},3)   = 8$
d=3; $t(\{2\},2)     = 3$
d=6; $t(\{1\},1)     = 1$
where all factors $t(\{\},d)$ are equal to 1.
Sofar we already have:
$c_r(\{4,1,1\})= \frac{1}{6} (840 \gamma(r,6,1)- 8 \gamma(r,6,2) +3 \gamma(r,6,3) + \gamma(r,6,6))$

Using the values at $r=3$ of $\gamma(r,6,d)$ calculated above, we then find
$c_4(\{4,1,1\}) = (1/6)(840 -8(-1)+ (3)(2) -2) = 142$.
Check:
$s_{\{4,1,1\}}(1,q,q^2,..,q^5)$ under $q^j=q^{j \pmod 6}$ equals 
$140+141q^1+138q^2+\mathbf
{142q^3}+138q^4+141q^5$
I like the esthetics of the divisors appearing in $u1$ and $u2$ combining with the partition quotients in a natural way.

Comment: After a week or so, if you still don't have responses here, you might try this on MathOverflow.  It feels more appropriate there (with "reference request" since you're trying to find the name for something you suspect has already been developed).

Comment: Thanks to Gareth McCaughan, who emailed me with a simplified version:
g(r,n,d) =  sum of mu(d/s) s where s | (d,n,r) 
meaning s divides the intersection of the divisors of r, n and d.